# Sprockets File not Found Exception

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sprockets

I was trying out some sample applications for Rails. I created some
controllers and pages. But when i try to access one of them i get an
exception on the webpage:

---

```
Sprockets::FileNotFound in Pages#home
Showing c:/railscode/test_app/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
where line #6 raised:

couldn't find file 'jquery'
  (in c:/railscode/test_app/app/assets/javascripts/application.js:7)
Extracted source (around line #6):

    3: <head> 
    4:   <title>TestApp</title> 
    5:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application" %> 
    6:   <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %> 
    7:   <%= csrf_meta_tags %> 8: </head> 9: <body>

Rails.root:`c:/railscode/test_app`
```

---

I created some controllers using the command:

```
$ rails generate controller Pages home contact

  create  app/controllers/pages_controller.rb
   route  get "pages/contact"
   route  get "pages/home"
  invoke  erb
  create    app/views/pages
  create    app/views/pages/home.html.erb
  create    app/views/pages/contact.html.erb
  invoke  rspec
  create    spec/controllers/pages_controller_spec.rb
  create    spec/views/pages
  create    spec/views/pages/home.html.erb_spec.rb
  create    spec/views/pages/contact.html.erb_spec.rb
  invoke  helper
  create    app/helpers/pages_helper.rb
  invoke  rspec
  create     spec/helpers/pages_helper_spec.rb
  invoke  assets
  invoke    js
  create      app/assets/javascripts/pages.js
  invoke    css
  create      app/assets/stylesheets/pages.css
```

Just wanted to know where the problem could be and where to look? I am
accessing the page by the URL: http://localhost:3000/pages/home

Answer (score 18):

Un-commenting the line

```
//= require jquery
```

in application.js file and restarting the application is what worked for me.

Answer (score 11):

Had a similar problem with `FileNotFound` for `twitter/bootstrap` after installing http://metaskills.net/2011/09/26/less-is-more-using-twitter-bootstrap-in-the-rails-3-1-asset-pipeline/

I did `rake assets:clean assets:precompile`, but that didn't help. What helped was restarting the rails application as suggested by afaf12.

Comment: the old reliable - restart the server -- worked a treat. thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

For me, the solution was to run `yarn install`. YMMV

Answer (score 0):

It's quite possible that your `jquery-rails` gem is outdated. When I ran into a similar error, updating the gem solved the issue.

Did you create this as a Rails 3.1 application from scratch? Or are you downloading code from somewhere (or updating an older app)?

Answer (score 0):

In rails 6.x.x the problem can be solved by executing

```
bundle exec rails webpacker:install
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a comment to your `config/initialize/assets` and then restart your `rails server`.

```
Rails.application.config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('node_modules')
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).